# Power BI How to display duplicate data from two or more worksheets

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

[image]
I am working on a project to consolidate audit findings from multiple sites.  The effort is to have a report that contains duplicate findings 2 or more sites. Currently, I am working with 3 sites, but this will increase to 50+.

I have not used Power BI, Power Query, or queries before - so this is all new to me.  So far I've found Power BI to be a bit easier for me, so that is what I am currently trying to work this out in.

I have transformed the data from 3 separate worksheets, from 3 workbooks.  So I have data from 3 worksheets (column2 and column4). Column2 is the identification number and 4 is the description.  The numbers are mixed - i.e.: 1.1-1, etc.

When I apply filters for 2 worksheets I do get the return I expected.  If I apply filters for 3 worksheets I only get data common in all 3.  This does make sense to me - I just now need to figure out how to properly do a query that would return matches for worksheet1 and/or worksheet2 and/or worksheet3.

In Power BI I have tried to add a column and do a query statement, but I severely lack the knowledge to do this.

Here is one of the statements I wrote. My thinking is if worksheet1 and worksheet2 have a match then display that # from worksheet1.

```
Column = (IF (('worksheet1'[column2] = 'worksheet2[column2]), (worksheet1[column2]))
```

If this worked the plan was to continue with a check for worksheet1/3 and worksheet2/3.

Comment: you need to post sample data and desired output. Otherwise, we can't tell what you have or what you are trying to do from your description

Comment: What is the ultimate goal ? To get the non repeating items when all the tables are combined or to line them up for some reason

Comment: The goal is to get repeating items. Each worksheet corresponds to a facility that has been audited.

Answer (score 0):

I would put all the files you want to import into a single folder, and use a Folder Source in PowerQuery. Then you can loop over the tables (as well as including the filename, if you need to, in your imported data). Then in PowerQuery, you could Group By all the columns that should be the same and get a count. The count will be stored in your table, so you can then filter those records so you return anything with a count less than your threshold. Then those will be the only records in your report. (If you click on the column in PowerQuery, you should get a context-sensitive menu with the commands you can use.)

You might want to start slowly with Group By until you get your head around it - maybe with a few small dummy files with only a handful of records each. Then once you have the logic right, switch your folder to the real one.